# Flutter orientation change stuttering

Tags: flutter

I'm experiencing a stuttering when the device orientation is changing, see video below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Psmoi4NJ-aA

As you can see when changing the orientation from portrait to landscape nearly half of the screen is showing a black area and the green area under the centred text is gone for a small period.

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
          return Container(
            color: orientation == Orientation.portrait
                ? Colors.green
                : Colors.blue,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "${orientation.toString()}",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .headline6
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea what could cause the issue ? Could it be a device related issue ?
My device specs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know what causes the issue, but I just tried your example with Flutter 2.2.3 • channel stable and Simulator (iPhone 12 Pro 2 - 14.4) and works smoothly.

Comment: Hi János! Forgot to mention the device specs I'm facing the issue on.